# Why doesn't Kile use my build arguments?

Tags: pdftex, kile, memory

Currently, I am working on a .tex file on Windows using Kile editor. If I use the following command to compile the file via terminal, everything works fine:

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --extra-mem-top=10000000 --synctex=1 <myTexFile>.tex
```

Now I do not want to always have to use the terminal, so I wanted to set up Kile. Therefore I navigated to

```
Settings -> Configure Kile -> Tools -> Create
```

And then I chose PDFLaTeX. I edited following fields:

- Command: pdflatex
- Options: --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --extra-mem-top=10000000 --synctex=1 %source

And in the advanced tab:

- Type: "Execute outside of kile" (I also tried "Run in console")
- Class: LaTeX

But the options are not used by Kile and I get this error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size = 3000000]
```

What is the difference between command execution in the terminal and the command settings with the same options in Kile and how can I fix that?